# Magento Admin Session Issue after install SUPEE-10570

Tags: adminhtml, core-session, supee-10570

We use Magento 1.7 and recently installed patch SUPEE-10570v2. After that when we use admin, some time it's session out and redirect to the front-end home page(not admin login page). Please let me know any one experience this issue and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the change that needs to be applied.

overrides file by copy "app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php" to "app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php" and write below code in it.

```
class Mage_Core_Model_Session extends Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract
{
public function __construct($data=array())
{
    $name = isset($data['name']) ? $data['name'] : null;
    $this->init('core', $name);
}

/**
 * Retrieve Session Form Key
 *
 * @return string A 16 bit unique key for forms
 */
public function getFormKey()
{
    if (!$this->getData('_form_key')) {
        //$this->setData('_form_key', Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(16));
        $this->renewFormKey();
    }
    return $this->getData('_form_key');
}

public function renewFormKey()
{
    $this->setData('_form_key', Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(16));
}
public function validateFormKey($formKey)
{
    return ($formKey === $this->getFormKey());
}
}
```

Comment: Those changes are already applied with patch 7405. Normally we maintain all patches. we faced this issue after install SUPEE-10570